# In this code how i can access two or more properties at a time using FOR loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, multidimensional-array, filter, properties

```
    const array1 = [
        [
            {crow : 'black',
            pigon : 'white',
            parrot : 'green',}
        ],
        [
            {apple : 'red',
            orange : 'green',
            mango : 'yellow'}
        ]
    ]
```

Please must answer! How i can access two or more properties of this nested array using loop or even filter() function.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: let valueAccessing = array1.filter((user)=>user[0] = 'green')
        console.log(valueAccessing)                                                                                                      like this code i want to access the properties whose value = green.

Comment: That hasn’t cleared things up.

Comment: let valueAccessing = array1.filter((user)=>user[0] = 'green') 
       console.log(valueAccessing)                                                                                                 This is remaining code of my question that can i access the nested array propertis of value green by such an above way?                                                                                                               now if u can  understand so please answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array1.forEach(arr => {
   // arr[0] is your object
   let crow = arr[0].crow;
   let pigon= arr[0].crow;
   let parrot= arr[0].crow;
})
```

But this will fit only for array1[0]
so better is to for loop about all the object keys

```
array1.forEach((arr, i) => {
   // arr[0] is your object
   const entries = Object.entries(arr[0])
   console.log(entries) 
})
```

the result is :

```
0: (2) ["crow", "black"]
1: (2) ["pigon", "white"]
2: (2) ["parrot", "green"]

0: (2) ["apple", "red"]
1: (2) ["orange", "green"]
2: (2) ["mango", "yellow"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the array has 2 elements, you can refer to each element using the index number.
The first element is in index 0 while the second is in index 1.e.g array1[0], array1[1]
Use a for loop to loop through the array elements and print out each objects

```
array1[0].forEach(function(firstelement){
    console.log("Crow: "+ firstelement.crow)
    console.log("Pigon: "+ firstelement.pigon)
    console.log("Parrot: "+ firstelement.parrot)

}) 

array1[1].forEach(function(secondelement){
    console.log("Apple: "+ secondelement.apple)
    console.log("Orange: "+ secondelement.orange)
    console.log("Mango : "+ secondelement.mango)

})
```

Comment: good try! but not the answer of my question!     I asked how i can access the keys through values of Array of nested object?

Answer (score -1):

```
array1.filter((arr) =>
    document.write(arr.filter((arr1)=>{
        console.log(Object.keys(arr1)[Object.values(arr1).indexOf('green')])
    }))
)
```

This is the exact answer of my question which no one could solve!
Anyways Thank You all `enter code here`for trying best!